# Apps open multiple window instances and then the system hangs

Tags: 20.04

Whenever I open any app or browser the app's window starts multiplying and when there are too many apps opened then it starts multiplying and the laptop hangs. I have noticed that sometimes when I install any application the windows of that store or terminal starts multiplying.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110204/discussion-on-question-by-neel-paul-apps-open-multiple-window-instances-and-then).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**vm.swappiness**

With only 4G RAM, setting vm.swappiness=10 is totally wrong.

Set vm.swappiness=60 (based on 4G RAM and 4G SWAP), this way...

`sudo -H gedit /etc/sysctl.conf` # edit this file

Search for an existing `vm.swappiness=` entry...

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> vm.swappiness

- If found, **edit** it to say `vm.swappiness=60`
- If not found, **add** `vm.swappiness=60` at the end of the file

Save your edits and quit gedit

`sudo sysctl -p`

**swap**

With only 4G RAM, your /swapfile, or swap partition, is too small. We need to increase it to 4G.

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `dd` command can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 4G RAM and 4G swap
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```

Add this line to /etc/fstab if it doesn't already exist... and remove any other swap lines that may be there... edit with `sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab`...

```
/swapfile    none    swap    sw      0   0
```